# text wrongly matchs with sub string of words in group

Tags: java, regex

I want to check the text to see if it starts with what or who and and is a question type, so for that I wrote the following code:

```
private static void startWithQOrIf(String commentstr){

     String urlPattern = "(|who|what).*\\?.*$";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
}
```

everything works good but for example when I try:

```
whooooooooo is the follower?
```

will match as well but should not because I am looking for who not whooooooooo

Any idea?

Comment: do you know what this `(|who|what)` does?

Comment: @AvinashRaj thank u yes I learnt in one of the answers below . thank u for being careful about that though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ensure a whole word using a word boundary `\b`:

```
(|who|what)\\b.*\\?.*$
            ^^
```

If the words in the alternation group are supposed to appear at the start of the string, you can just use `matches` and remove `$` anchor:

```
 String urlPattern = "(|who|what)\\b.*\\?.*";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr);
    if (m.matches()) {                        // < - Here, matches is used
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
```

Note that `(|who|what)` matches either an empty string, or `who`, or `what`. If you do not plan to allow empty string, use just `(who|what)`.

Answer (score 2):

You must use word boundaries.

```
String urlPattern = "\\b(who|what)\\b.*\\?.*$";
```